# limit item selection from listbox in asp.net using vb

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i want to restrict the number of item selection from the listbox in asp.net using vb. I was trying it using javascript. But, not working. Need help

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbprefferedlocation" runat="server" DataSourceID="locations" 
                DataTextField="City_Name" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkCount(this)" DataValueField="City_Name" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenChkCount" runat="server" />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="locations" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JPConnString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [City_Name] FROM [State_Info]"></asp:SqlDataSource>



function chkCount(obj)
{
    if(obj.checked==true)
    {
        if( document.getElementById( '<%=hiddenChkCount.ClientID %>' ).value >= 5 )
        {
            alert('You cannot select more than 5 items.');
            obj.checked=false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById( '<%=hiddenChkCount.ClientID %>' ).value = parseInt( document.getElementById( '<%=hiddenChkCount.ClientID %>' ).value ) + 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById( '<%=hiddenChkCount.ClientID %>' ).value = parseInt( document.getElementById( '<%=hiddenChkCount.ClientID %>' ).value) - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CustomValidator`:

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CV_CheckLocationCount" runat="server"
     ValidateEmptyText="true" 
     ClientValidationFunction="CheckLocationCount"
     OnServerValidate="CheckLocationCount" 
     ControlToValidate="lbprefferedlocation"
     EnableClientScript="true" 
     ErrorMessage="Select at least one and at most 5 locations"
     ValidationGroup="VG_SAVE">*
</asp:CustomValidator>

function CheckLocationCount(sender, args){
    var count=$('#<%=lbprefferedlocation.ClientID %> option:selected').length;
    args.IsValid = count > 0 && count <= 5;
}
```

**Edit**: And here's a non jQuery solution:

```
function validateListBoxSelectionCount(listbox, minSelected, maxSelected){
    var selected=0;
    if(listbox != null){
        for (var i=0; i<listbox.length; i++){
            if(listbox.options[i].selected){
               selected++; 
               if(selected>maxSelected)break;
            }
        }
    }
   return (selected >= minSelected && selected <= maxSelected);
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
var listBox  = document.getElementById("<%=lbprefferedlocation.ClientID %>");
args.IsValid = validateListBoxSelectionCount(listBox, 1, 5);
```

Comment: 'CheckLocationCount' is not a member

Comment: @coders_zone: Maybe because you haven't provided `CheckLocationCount`on serverside. You should **always** validate on client- and on serverside.

Comment: so what should i write in serverside..??

Comment: @coders_zone: `protected void CheckLocationCounton(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = lbprefferedlocation.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i=>i.Selected).Count() <= 5;
}
`

Comment: @coders_zone: `args.IsValid = lbprefferedlocation.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)().Where(Function(i)i.Selected).Count() <= 5`